# How do I apply a function on each value of a column in a SPARKR DataFrame?

Tags: r, sparkr

I am relatively new to SPARKR. I downloaded SPARK 1.4 and setup RStudio to use SPARKR library. However I want to know how I can apply a function to each value in a column of a distributed DataFrame, can someone please help?
For example,

This works perfectly

```
myFunc <- function(x) { paste(x , "_hello")}
c <- c("a", "b", "c")
d <- lapply(c, myFunc)
```

How to make this work for a Distributed DataFrame. 
The intention is to append "_hello" to each value of column Name of DF

```
DF <- read.df(sqlContext, "TV_Flattened_2.csv", source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
SparkR:::lapply(DF$Name, myFunc)
```

In the alpha version of SPARKR before SPARK 1.4 release there seems to have been this ability, why is this now missing in SPARK 1.4 official release?

Comment: I have no knowledge of sparkr but could it be you rather need `name(DF)` instead of `DF$Name` ?

Comment: Under the hood, the lapply function is still part of SparkR 1.4, but for the moment it is no global function, I have no idea why. You should as well look to the map function.

Answer (score 2):

Using flatMap, you create an RDD from a DataFrame with the function applied on all items.

```
c <- c("a", "b", "c")
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, as.data.frame(c))
myFunc <- function(x) { paste(x , "_hello")}
d <- flatMap(df, myFunc)
e <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, d)
```

The disadvantage however, is that only does what you expect on the first column of the DataFrame, it skips all other columns. This is seen in the following example:

```
c <- c("a", "b", "c")
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, as.data.frame(c,u=c(1,2,3)))
myFunc <- function(x) { paste(x , "_hello")}
d <- flatMap(df, myFunc)
e <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, d)
```

which gives exactly the same output as the first example, however df started with an extra column.

Comment: It seems that the `flatMap` is not exported in 2.1, I had to do: `SparkR:::flatMap(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Spark 2.x now has a function called dapply which allows you to run a R function on each partition of a SparkR dataframe.

Code sample from docs:

```
# Convert waiting time from hours to seconds.
# Note that we can apply UDF to DataFrame.
schema <- structType(structField("eruptions", "double"), structField("waiting", "double"),
                     structField("waiting_secs", "double"))
df1 <- dapply(df, function(x) { x <- cbind(x, x$waiting * 60) }, schema)
head(collect(df1))
##  eruptions waiting waiting_secs
##1     3.600      79         4740
##2     1.800      54         3240
##3     3.333      74         4440
##4     2.283      62         3720
##5     4.533      85         5100
##6     2.883      55         3300
```

See here for more information:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#run-a-given-function-on-a-large-dataset-using-dapply-or-dapplycollect

Just note that if you are using any external R libraries, you will need to have these installed on the worker nodes

Comment: I tried to get `gapply` to work but it was so tricky but yours worked perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: Regarding external libraries, you can load libraries in the function as well by adding `library(x)` at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I played with this quite a bit and don't have a clean solution to apply the function directly to column elements and frankly am not sure this is currently possible.  Nonetheless, using the COLLECT method we can do the following:

Note am using a Windows and type into powershell

```
cd D:\Spark\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6
./bin/sparkR
c <- c("a", "b", "c")
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, as.data.frame(c))
c1 <- collect(df)
myFunc <- function(x) { paste(x , "_hello")}
d <- lapply(c1, myFunc)
df2 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, as.data.frame(d))
head(df2)
```

Produces what you'd print in R:
1 a _hello
2 b _hello
3 c _hello

Here are useful resources:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/08/12/from-pandas-to-apache-sparks-dataframe.html

Comment: This approach is serial. Calling collect on the dataframe means this will not distribute the work among the executors.