# Cross tabulating missing values in SparkR data frame across all columns

Tags: r, apache-spark, na, crosstab, sparkr

I'm interested in arriving at a cross-tab of missing values across all columns in SparkR data frame. The data I'm trying to utilise can be generated with use of the code below:

## Data

```
set.seed(2)

# Create basic matrix
M <- matrix(
    nrow = 100,
    ncol = 100,
    data = base::sample(x = letters, size = 1e4, replace = TRUE)
)


## Force missing vales
M[base::sample(1:nrow(M), 10),
  base::sample(1:ncol(M), 10)] <- NA
table(is.na(M))
```

## `SparkR`

Following, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32043454/1655567) I would like to arrive at the desired solution using `flatMap`. The idea is to replace missing / non-missing values with `T/F` and then count occurrences for each variable. First it appears that `flatMap` was no exported by SparkR 2.1 so I had to dig it out with **`:::`**

```
# Import data to SparkR ---------------------------------------------------

# Feed data into SparkR
dtaSprkM <- createDataFrame(sqc, as.data.frame(M))
## Preview
describe(dtaSprkM)
# Missing values count ----------------------------------------------------

# Function to convert missing to T/F
convMiss <- function(x) {
    ifelse(test = isNull(x),
           yes = FALSE,
           no = TRUE)
}

# Apply
dtaSprkMTF <- SparkR:::flatMap(dtaSprkM, isNull)
## Derive data frame
dtaSprkMTFres <- createDataFrame(sqc, dtaSprkMTF)
```

Second, after running the code fails with the following error message:

```
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘isNull’ for signature ‘"list"’
```

## Desired results

On an ordinary data frame in R the desired results can be achieved in the following manner

```
sapply(as.data.frame(M), function(x) {
    prop.table(table(is.na(x)))
})
```

---

I like the flexibility that `table` and `prop.table` offer and ideally I would like to be able to arrive at similar flexibility via SparkR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute fraction of `NULL` per column:

```
fractions <- select(dtaSprkM, lapply(columns(dtaSprkM), function(c) 
    alias(avg(cast(isNotNull(dtaSprkM[[c]]), "integer")), c)
)
```

This will create a single row `Data.Frame` which can be safely collected and easily reshaped locally, for example with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

fractions %>% as.data.frame %>% gather(variable, fraction_not_null)
```